# BMW 535i "Engine Compartment Hot" and "Engine Overheating" issue

Tags: bmw, overheating

I did the whole oil-change shabang on my BMW 535i 2013 car just a few months ago (Feb 2022) so I was shocked when the Engine overheating light came on today and the engine did overheat such that the car stopped. Assuming the engine coolant compartment is the canister to the bottom right (when facing the hood) I put a straw in it and it appears there's still fluid left so I am curious if y'all have any thoughts as to what it might be and what it will take/cost to fix it. Also what do you recommend (can we still keep driving it as it is?)? Here's a video I recorded somewhat showing the issue: https://youtu.be/38kI7kQ6l4E
Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it's the electric water pump particularly with the noise you mention. Check this video out which tells you how to test the water pump - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JCRRBUlX3s.

Answer (score 0):

If there's still plenty of coolant in the system I'd be inclined to think main water pump or (possibly *and*) thermostat.

The water pump is a pretty common point of failure on those - and if you're swapping that it makes sense to do thermostat at the same time.